# $.post- How to tell what data to send?

Tags: jquery, post

Im looking at this page- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and this portion-

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Are "name" and "time" both names of the elements on the form? If not, what elements of the form do they represent?

Answer (score 2):

There is no form involved here, but `name` and `time` are the keys for the values `John` and `2pm` sent in the request, yes.

The request body ends up looking like this:

```
name=John&time=2pm
```

Comment: So what if you were sending a form? Could you show me an example of that?

Comment: @Alex: Do you mean “how do I get the values of input elements”?

Comment: Okay I guess ill give a tad more info. Im trying to create an account using the post method on this https://www.roblox.com/Login/Signup.aspx . I just dont know how to send the form to the server.

Comment: @Alex: You’d use `serialize`, then, as the other answers point out. Or get each element individually, like `{username: $('#username').val()}`. Oh, and just in case you’re trying to send this request from your own site to the Roblox one — cross-domain requests don’t work in general for security reasons unless specifically allowed.

Comment: The name of the password field on the page above is `ctl00$cphRoblox$ctl00$UserName` & the id is `UserName`. To fill in that input, how would that look? Something like- `{ctl00$cphRoblox$ctl00$UserName: $('#username').val()}`

Comment: @Alex: Yes, but `$('#UserName')`, not `$('#username')`. Just use `serialize` to submit the whole thing :)

Answer (score 2):

They do not represent any element of your form; they are just parameters sent with your request, equivalent to this get request:

```
test.php?name=John&time=2pm
```

If you want to send form, you can use `.serialize`:

```
$.post("test.php", $('form').serialize() );
```